# Who is the νομοθέτης mentioned in James 4:12?

Tags: jesus, trinity

> There is **one** lawgiver, who is able to save and to **destroy**: who art thou that judgest another? KJV  James 4:12

Did Jesus have power to destroy unclean spirits πνεύματι ἀκαθάρτῳ? If so, what does the term εἷς represent?

Comment: There are two quite separate questions that should be asked separately.

Comment: It's just a question, depending on the answer other questions will happen. In the case, if Jesus destroys spirits, the word "one" is not singular.

Comment: It is not singular as, for example, the dream reported in Genesis 41:25-31, were two dreams that were one, a construct state in Hebrew.

Comment: What do you mean by unclean spirit? A human spirit, fallen angels, evil spirits not from the Adamic race?

Answer (score 1):

Here is my literal translation of James 4:12 -

> One is lawgiver and judge, the one able to save and destroy. But who
> are you to judge your neighbor?

The one lawgiver and judge is obviously the Lord God Himself as per Matt 10:28 -

> Do not be afraid of those who kill the body but cannot kill the soul.
> Instead, fear the One who can destroy both soul and body in hell.

Note the comments of Ellicott who is typical of many commentators (eg, Barnes, JFB, Poole, Gill, Pulpit, etc)

> (12) **There is one lawgiver** . . . .—Better thus: One is the
> Law-giver and Judge, Who is able to save and to destroy: but thou—who
> art thou that judgest a neighbour? As a king is the fountain of
> honour, so the ultimate source of law is God; and all judgment really
> is delegated by Him, just as ordinary courts represent the royal
> majesty: to usurp such functions is to provoke the offended
> sovereign—whether of earth or heaven. “It is not our part,” said
> Bengel, “to judge, since we cannot carry out our sentence.” (Comp. a
> parallel scripture, Romans 14:4.)
>
> **Able to save and to destroy**.—Life and death, salvation and utter destruction, seem to be placed in intentional contrast here. (Comp.
> Matthew 10:28.)

I will not address the question of whether Jesus had the power to destroy unclean spirits because it is not germane to the main question.  [The OP should ask this separately.]

Answer (score 0):

This is another case where the context is very helpfful.

In v11, James says "Do not speak evil against one another, brethren" (RSV), and we can see on reading through these two verses that they are addressed to such "evil-speakers".

If that introduction were followed by v12 alone,it would be a re-wording of Matthew ch7 vv1-2; "Judge not, that you be not judged. For with the judgment you pronounce you will be judged." Jesus would be identifying God as the judge, and we are shown elsewhere in the N.T. that judgment is delivered through Christ (e.g. Matthew ch24), who works closely together with his Father (John ch5 vv19-23). So the "one judge" could be referred to God, or to the combined will of Father and Son.

But the remainder of v11 adds another element to the picture. James is particularly addressing those who "judge the law" and thus make themselves judges over it and other people. In doing do, they are effectively taking the place of the one who gave the law in the first place. The rest of the Bible shows us that God alone is the true giver of law and the rightful judge.

James has also just said that those who speak evil against or judge their brethren are judging the law at the same time. I believe the best explanation of this verdict is that James is giving his warning in the middle of fierce debate about the value of the law. For even Paul agrees, e.g. Romans ch3 v27, that there is a good aspect to law as well as a bad aspect. In that case, the "evil-speakers" could be over-zealous critics of the law, "judging" fiercely those among the brethren who try to defend it. Perhaps the critics are followers of Paul who are pushing his words too far. These critics would be the ones who are being rebuked in the rest of the passage.

I think the short answer to your question is that the one law-giver has to be God, in which case "saving and destroying" would be a reference to the final judgement.